# How can I simplify the expression $k<\frac{n}{n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}+1/2}$ using the big O notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

I'm learning about big O notation and I'm having problems with this exercise.
Let be $n$ and $k$ positive integers, how can I simplify the expression $k<\frac{n}{n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}+1/2}$ using a dominant power of $n$ and and a big O of a menor power of $n$. This is what I have done:

$k<\frac{n}{n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}+1/2}$, we know that for some positive $C$ we have that $-Cn^{1/4}\leq n^{1/4}+1/2\leq Cn^{1/4}$, then $k<\frac{n}{n^{1/2}-O(n^{1/4})}$, so $k<\frac{n^{1/2}}{1-O(n^{-1/4})}$.
Then $k(1-O(n^{-1/4}))<n^{1/2}$, so $k-kO(n^{-1/4})<n^{1/2}$.

I want to change the $k$ in the expression $-kO(n^{-1/4})$ in terms of some power o $n$ and I have been struggling with that. Any one have any advice?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Make $n=x^4$ and long division to $O(1/x)$ and replace $x$ by $n^{1/4}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large $n$, you have $n^{1/2}\gg n^{1/4}\gg 1/2$, so give $n^{1/2}$ as a factor.
$$k<\frac{n}{n^{1/2}(1+n^{-1/4}+1/2n^{-1/2})}$$
$n^{-1/4}$ and $1/2n^{-1/2}$ are small. Then use $$\frac1{1+x}\approx 1-x$$
Therefore $$k<n^{1/2}(1-O(n^{-1/4}))=n^{1/2}-O(n^{1/4})$$

Comment: Now I get it, thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark it as accepted if you think it completely answers your question.